# Optimizing simple CPU-bound loops using Cython and replacing a list

Tags: performance, loops, numpy, cython

I am trying to evaluate some approaches, and I'm hitting a stumbling block with performance.

Why is my cython code so slow??  My expectation is that the code would run quite a bit faster (maybe nano seconds for a 2d loop with only 256 ** 2 entries) as opposed to milliseconds.

Here are my test results:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace; python test.py
running build_ext
        counter: 0.00236220359802 sec
       pycounter: 0.00323309898376 sec
      percentage: 73.1 %
```

My initial code looks something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
# filename: loop_testing.py

def generate_coords(dim, length):
    """Generates a list of coordinates from dimensions and size
    provided.

    Parameters:
        dim -- dimension
        length -- size of each dimension

    Returns:
        A list of coordinates based on dim and length
    """
    values = []
    if dim == 2:
        for x in xrange(length):
            for y in xrange(length):
                values.append((x, y))

    if dim == 3:
        for x in xrange(length):
            for y in xrange(length):
                for z in xrange(length):
                    values.append((x, y, z))

    return values
```

This works for what I need, but is slow.  For a given dim, length = (2, 256), I see a timing on iPython of approximately 2.3ms.

In an attempt to speed this up, I developed a cython equivalent (I think it's an equivalent).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8
# filename: loop_testing.pyx
# cython: boundscheck=False
# cython: wraparound=False

cimport cython
from cython.parallel cimport prange

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


ctypedef int DTYPE

# 2D point updater
cpdef inline void _counter_2d(DTYPE[:, :] narr, int val) nogil:
    cdef:
        DTYPE count = 0
        DTYPE index = 0
        DTYPE x, y

    for x in range(val):
        for y in range(val):
            narr[index][0] = x
            narr[index][1] = y
            index += 1

cpdef DTYPE[:, :] counter(dim=2, val=256):
    narr = np.zeros((val**dim, dim), dtype=np.dtype('i4'))
    _counter_2d(narr, val)
    return narr

def pycounter(dim=2, val=256):
    vals = []
    for x in xrange(val):
        for y in xrange(val):
            vals.append((x, y))
    return vals
```

And the invocation of the timing:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# filename: test.py
"""
Usage:
    test.py [options]
    test.py [options] <val>
    test.py [options] <dim> <val>

Options:
    -h --help       This Message
    -n              Number of loops [default: 10]
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from docopt import docopt
    from timeit import Timer

    args = docopt(__doc__)
    dim = args.get("<dim>") or 2
    val = args.get("<val>") or 256
    n = args.get("-n") or 10
    dim = int(dim)
    val = int(val)
    n = int(n)

    tests = ['counter', 'pycounter']
    timing = {}
    for test in tests:
        code = "{}(dim=dim, val=val)".format(test)
        variables = "dim, val = ({}, {})".format(dim, val)
        setup = "from loop_testing import {}; {}".format(test, variables)
        t = Timer(code, setup=setup)
        timing[test] = t.timeit(n) / n

    for test, val in timing.iteritems():
        print "{:>20}: {} sec".format(test, val)
    print "{:>20}: {:>.3} %".format("percentage", timing['counter'] / timing['pycounter'] * 100)
```

And for reference, the setup.py to build the cython code:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

include_path = [numpy.get_include()]

setup(
    name="looping",
    ext_modules=cythonize('loop_testing.pyx'),  # accepts a glob pattern
    include_dirs=include_path,
)
```

**EDIT:**
Link to working version: https://github.com/brianbruggeman/cython_experimentation

Comment: Your cython code is pretty good. Exept that `narr[index][0] = x` does not actually do the assignment (and does slow C python API calls), use `narr[index,0] = x` instead (same is true for pure numpy). Also, try setting  `extra_compile_args=['-O3', '-march=native']` and `extra_link_args=['-O3', '-march=native']` in your `setup.py` that should speed things up.

Comment: @rth `narr[index, 0]` definitely fixed the issue.  I'm at about 100x speedup now.  I didn't see much change with the extra compilation / linking options.  However, I do not mind leaving those in at this point.  Thanks a ton!  Would you like to add an Answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This Cython code was slow because of the `narr[index][0] = x` assignment, which relies heavily on Python C-API. Using, `narr[index, 0] = x` instead, is translated to pure C, and solves this issue.

As pointed out by @perimosocordiae, using `cythonize` with annotations  is definitely the way to go to debug such issues.

In some cases it can also be worth explicitly specifying compilation flags in `setup.py` for gcc,

```
setup(
   [...]
   extra_compile_args=['-O2', '-march=native'],
   extra_link_args=['-O2', '-march=native'])
```

This should not be necessary, assuming reasonable default compilation flags. However, for instance, on my Linux system the default appear to be no optimization at all and adding the above flags, results in a significant performance improvement.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your Cython code is doing some strange things with numpy arrays, and isn't really taking advantage of the C compilation. To check the generated code, run

```
cython -a loop_testing.pyx
```

What happens if you avoid the numpy parts and do a straightforward Cython translation of the Python function?

**EDIT**: It looks like you can avoid Cython entirely for a pretty decent speedup. (~30x on my machine)

```
def npcounter(dim=2, val=256):
  return np.indices((val,)*dim).reshape((dim,-1)).T
```

Comment: That was my next step.  I really wanted to avoid malloc if I could.  I am using the numpy pieces to allocate memory.

Comment: You can make lists and append to them using Cython. Start there, before you wade into malloc.

Comment: I thought I was trying to avoid the lists... appending in python implies I'm using the python interpreter to add to a python object.  I don't want to use the objects, from what I've been reading/seeing.

https://gist.github.com/brianbruggeman/625e488777722e852e6c

No appreciable difference.

Comment: @perimosocordiae There is nothing wrong with numpy arrays, in this particular case, they should be much faster than using python lists.

Comment: @rth: The weird indexing looked suspicious to me, but I suppose there isn't anything very wrong there.

Comment: @perimosocordiae Well  actually now that you mention indexing, the problem with that code was that `narr[index][0] = x` was used for assignment, which does not work with numpy. Btw, good point for the vectorized pure numpy solution.

Comment: The issue with the numpy is that I have other operations I'd like to perform rather than simple assignment.  But simple assignment is the sort of basic operation I can think of that comes close.   Cython really shouldn't be 30x slower, which makes me think I'm doing something specific wrong.