# Numba and numpy array allocation: why is it so slow?

Tags: python, numpy, numba

I recently played with Cython and Numba to accelerate small pieces of a python that does numerical simulation. At first, developing with numba seems easier. Yet, I found difficult to understand when numba will provide a better performance and when it will not.

One example of unexpected performance drop is when I use the function `np.zeros()` to allocate a big array in a compiled function. For example, consider the three function definitions:

```py
import numpy as np 
from numba import jit 

def pure_python(n):
    mat = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.double)
    # do something
    return mat.reshape((n**2))

@jit(nopython=True)
def pure_numba(n):
    mat = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.double)
    # do something
    return mat.reshape((n**2))

def mixed_numba1(n):
    return mixed_numba2(np.zeros((n,n)))

@jit(nopython=True)

def mixed_numba2(array):
    n = len(array)
    # do something
    return array.reshape((n,n))

# To compile 
pure_numba(10)
mixed_numba1(10)
```

Since the `#do something` is empty, I do not expect the `pure_numba` function to be faster. Yet, I was not expecting such a performance drop:

```py
n=10000
%timeit x = pure_python(n)
%timeit x = pure_numba(n)
%timeit x = mixed_numba1(n)
```

I obtain (python 3.7.7, numba 0.48.0 on a mac)

```
4.96 µs ± 65.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
344 ms ± 7.76 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
3.8 µs ± 30.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Here, the numba code is much slower when I use the function `np.zeros()` inside the compiled function. It works normally when the `np.zeros()` is outside the function.

Am I doing something wrong here or should I always allocate big arrays like these outside functions that are compiled by numba?

**Update**

This seems related to a lazy initialization of the matrices by `np.zeros((n,n))` when `n` is large enough (see [Performance of zeros function in Numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487786/performance-of-zeros-function-in-numpy) ).

```py
for n in [1000, 2000, 5000]:
    print('n=',n)
    %timeit x = pure_python(n)
    %timeit x = pure_numba(n)
    %timeit x = mixed_numba1(n)
```

gives me:

```
n = 1000
468 µs ± 15.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
296 µs ± 6.55 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
300 µs ± 2.26 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
n = 2000
4.79 ms ± 182 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.45 ms ± 36 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.54 ms ± 127 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
n = 5000
270 µs ± 4.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
104 ms ± 599 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
119 µs ± 1.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

Comment: This may have something to do with how `np.zeros` works under the hood, try it with a larger `n` or don't use `.zeros`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487786/performance-of-zeros-function-in-numpy

Comment: It looks like that could be it @juanpa. Trying with np.empty and geting reasonable timings. The timings on the mixed and pure python functions though seem wrong. Can you double check N. Gast?

Comment: The Numpy version maybe lazily allocate memory (in this case no allocation at all). Add a simple operation eg. mat[:,:]=1.1 to check if that happens.

Comment: I double check the timing and they are correct. This is probably related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44487786/performance-of-zeros-function-in-numpy : the pure python code is faster for n=10000 than for n=1000 (this is also true if I replace the "# do somthing" by something like "for i in range(10):  mat[np.random.randint(n),np.random.randint(n)] = 1"

Comment: see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50658884/why-this-numba-code-is-6x-slower-than-numpy-code) it may have elements to understand the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**tl;dr Numpy uses C memory functions whereas Numba must assign zeros**

I wrote a script to plot the time it takes for several options to complete and it appears that Numba has a severe drop in performance when the size of the `np.zeros` array reaches `2048*2048*8 = 32 MB` on my machine as shown in the diagram below.

Numba's implementation of `np.zeros` is just as fast as creating an empty array and filling it with zeros by iterating over the dimensions of the array (this is the *Numba nested loop* green curve of the diagram). This can actually be double-checked by setting the `NUMBA_DUMP_IR` environment variable before running the script (see below). When comparing to the dump for `numba_loop` there is not much difference.

Interstingly, `np.zeros` gets a little boost passed the 32 MB threshold.

My best guess, although I am far from an expert, is that the 32 MB limit is an OS or hardware bottleneck coming from the amount of data that can fit in a cache for the same process. If this is exceeded, the operation of moving data in and out of the cache to operate on it is very time consuming.

By contrast, Numpy uses [calloc](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/590facafcbd454fc02f96aa52c1c3412d6cccd14/numpy/core/src/multiarray/alloc.c#L212-L232) to get some memory segment with a promise to fill the data with zeros when it will be accessed.

This is how far I got and I realise it's only half an answer but maybe someone more knowledgeable can shed some light on what is actually going on.

[image: Graph of time deltas for different options]

Numba IR dump:

```
---------------------------IR DUMP: pure_numba_zeros----------------------------
label 0:
    n = arg(0, name=n)                       ['n']
    $2load_global.0 = global(np: <module 'numpy' from '/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>) ['$2load_global.0']
    $4load_attr.1 = getattr(value=$2load_global.0, attr=zeros) ['$2load_global.0', '$4load_attr.1']
    del $2load_global.0                      []
    $10build_tuple.4 = build_tuple(items=[Var(n, script.py:15), Var(n, script.py:15)]) ['$10build_tuple.4', 'n', 'n']
    $12load_global.5 = global(np: <module 'numpy' from '/lib/python3.8/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py'>) ['$12load_global.5']
    $14load_attr.6 = getattr(value=$12load_global.5, attr=double) ['$12load_global.5', '$14load_attr.6']
    del $12load_global.5                     []
    $18call_function_kw.8 = call $4load_attr.1($10build_tuple.4, func=$4load_attr.1, args=[Var($10build_tuple.4, script.py:15)], kws=[('dtype', Var($14load_attr.6, script.py:15))], vararg=None) ['$10build_tuple.4', '$14load_attr.6', '$18call_function_kw.8', '$4load_attr.1']
    del $4load_attr.1                        []
    del $14load_attr.6                       []
    del $10build_tuple.4                     []
    mat = $18call_function_kw.8              ['$18call_function_kw.8', 'mat']
    del $18call_function_kw.8                []
    $24load_method.10 = getattr(value=mat, attr=reshape) ['$24load_method.10', 'mat']
    del mat                                  []
    $const28.12 = const(int, 2)              ['$const28.12']
    $30binary_power.13 = n ** $const28.12    ['$30binary_power.13', '$const28.12', 'n']
    del n                                    []
    del $const28.12                          []
    $32call_method.14 = call $24load_method.10($30binary_power.13, func=$24load_method.10, args=[Var($30binary_power.13, script.py:16)], kws=(), vararg=None) ['$24load_method.10', '$30binary_power.13', '$32call_method.14']
    del $30binary_power.13                   []
    del $24load_method.10                    []
    $34return_value.15 = cast(value=$32call_method.14) ['$32call_method.14', '$34return_value.15']
    del $32call_method.14                    []
    return $34return_value.15                ['$34return_value.15']
```

The script to produce the diagram:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit
from time import time
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

os.environ['NUMBA_DUMP_IR'] = '1'

def numpy_zeros(n):
    mat = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.double)
    return mat.reshape((n**2))

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_zeros(n):
    mat = np.zeros((n,n), dtype=np.double)
    return mat.reshape((n**2))

@jit(nopython=True)
def numba_loop(n):
    mat = np.empty((n * 2,n), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(mat.shape[1]):
            mat[i, j] = 0.
    return mat.reshape((2 * n**2))

# To compile
numba_zeros(10)
numba_loop(10)

os.environ['NUMBA_DUMP_IR'] = '0'

max_n = 4100
time_deltas = {
    'numpy_zeros': [],
    'numba_zeros': [],
    'numba_loop': [],
}
call_count = 10
for n in range(0, max_n, 10):
    for f in (numpy_zeros, numba_zeros, numba_loop):
        start = time()
        for i in range(call_count):
              x = f(n)
        delta = time() - start
        time_deltas[f.__name__].append(delta / call_count)
        print(f'{f.__name__:25} n = {n}: {delta}')
    print()

size = np.arange(0, max_n, 10) ** 2 * 8 / 1024 ** 2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xticks(np.arange(0, size[-1], 16))
plt.axvline(x=32, color='gray', lw=0.5)
ax.plot(size, time_deltas['numpy_zeros'], label='Numpy zeros (calloc)')
ax.plot(size, time_deltas['numba_zeros'], label='Numba zeros')
ax.plot(size, time_deltas['numba_loop'], label='Numba nested loop')
ax.set_xlabel('Size of array in MB')
ax.set_ylabel(r'Mean $\Delta$t in s')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.show()
```

Comment: To me, my understanding of all this is that for large arrays `numpy.zeros()` is lazy and only allocates the elements when they are used.

Comment: @N.Gast Absolutely, `numpy.zeros` is lazy and extremely efficient because it leverages the C memory API which has been fine-tuned for the last 48 years. Numba is great at translating Python to machine language but doesn't have access to the C memory API. Note that `numba` could leverage C too but there is little point since numpy is already providing what is probably the best method in this case.

Comment: And also, Numba does a great job at creating zero-arrays less than 32MB (machine dependent) with perf similar to Numpy so in most cases, you don't mind whether Numpy or Numba creates the array.