# Why Numba's "Eager compilation" slows down the execution

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter, numba

Attached a minimal example:

```
from numba import jit
import numba as nb
import numpy as np

@jit(nb.float64[:, :](nb.int32[:, :])) 
def go_fast(a): 
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):  
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) 
    return a + trace          

@jit 
def go_fast2(a): 
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):  
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) 
    return a + trace
```

Running in Jupyter:

```
x = np.arange(10000).reshape(100, 100)
%timeit go_fast(x)
%timeit go_fast2(x)
```

leads to

5.65 µs ± 27.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

3.8 µs ± 46.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Why the eager compilations leads to a slower execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing that the memory accesses are contiguous simplifies the life of an optimizer (here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49058949/5769463) for Cython, but similar holds for numba, even if clang is often more clever than gcc).

Your example seems to be such a case:

1. without "eager compilation" the numba will detect, that the data is C-contiguous and utilize it, e.g. for vectorization.
2. with eager compilation, you don't provide this information, thus the optimizer must take into account, that the memory accesses could be non-contiguous and will create a jit-code which is less performant than the first version.

Thus, you should provide a more precise signature:

```
@jit(nb.float64[:, ::1](nb.int32[:, ::1])) 
def go_fast3(a): 
    trace = 0.0
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):  
        trace += np.tanh(a[i, i]) 
    return a + trace
```

`[:,::1]` [tells numba](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#arrays), that the data will be C-contiguous and once this information is utilized:

```
x = np.arange(10000).astype(np.int32).reshape(100, 100)
%timeit go_fast(x)     # 15.6 µs ± 241 ns per loop
%timeit go_fast2(x)    # 8.2 µs ± 90.7 ns per loop
%timeit go_fast3(x)    # 8.2 µs ± 49.6 ns per loop
```

there is no difference for the eagerly compiled version.

Comment: Where I can find the guideline for the syntex that you have used?

Comment: @GideonKogan e.g. here: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/types.html#arrays

Comment: There are some things which could be mentioned additionally. If Numba detects non-contiguous arrays in jit-mode a function isn't recompiled if it is called with contiguous arrays after that. This is also a feature which often leads to confusion.

Comment: You say "even if clang is more clever then gcc", but shouldn't you say "numba" or "LLVM" instead of "clang"? clang is not used here right?

Comment: @JensRenders llvm would be the most correct. Numba/clang are frontends using llvm. With cython one uses clang frontend or gcc, this is the reason I used this pair.

Comment: A okay i though the clang was referring to numba, my bad.